# position node relative to current bounding box

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning

With

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw (2,2) circle (3cm);

\node at (current bounding box.north)[anchor=north]{north};
\node at (current bounding box.north west)[anchor=north west]{north west};
\node at (current bounding box.north east)[anchor=north east]{north east};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

one can position a `node` relative to the bounding box of the picture, using a set of given positions (`north`, `north west`, etc.).

[image]

I would like to position the text more freely within the `current bounding box`, e.g., at position `(0.45, 0.7)`, where `(0, 0)` is the lower left and `(1, 1)` the top right corner of the `current bounding box`.

How to achieve this?

Comment: `\path (current bouding box.south west) -- (current bounding box.north east) node[pos=0.7] {xxx};`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can calculate the coordinate using the `calc` library. Note that if you place nodes near the edge that sticks outside, the `current bounding box` node will change. If you don't want the bounding box to be changed you can add a `\useboundingbox` as in the below example.

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\newcommand\relcoord[2]{({$(current bounding box.south west)!#1!(current bounding box.south east)$} |- {$(current bounding box.south west)!#2!(current bounding box.north west)$})}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw (2,2) circle[radius=2.5cm];

\node at (current bounding box.north)[anchor=north]{north};
\node at (current bounding box.north west)[anchor=north west]{north west};
\node at (current bounding box.north east)[anchor=north east]{north east};

\useasboundingbox \relcoord{0}{0} rectangle \relcoord{1}{1};

\draw [use as bounding box,help lines,step=0.5cm] \relcoord{0}{0} grid \relcoord{1}{1};

\fill [red] \relcoord{0.6}{0.7} circle[radius=3pt];
\fill [blue] \relcoord{0.3}{0.4} circle[radius=3pt];

\foreach \x in {0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1} {
 \node at \relcoord{\x}{0.7}[anchor=center] {x};
 \node at \relcoord{0.7}{\x}[anchor=center] {x};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I see slight inaccuracies with `\foreach \x in {0,...,9} {
  \node at \relcoord{0.\x}{0.7}[anchor=center] {x};
}
\node at \relcoord{1.0}{0.7}[anchor=center] {x};

\foreach \x in {0,...,9} {
  \node at \relcoord{0.7}{0.\x}[anchor=center] {x};
}
\node at \relcoord{0.7}{1.0}[anchor=center] {x};
`, in particular for `\x=0`. Also, the two loops don't intersect exactly.

Comment: @NicoSchlömer When you place nodes that has content outside the bounding box the `current bounding box` will change. In my example, if you add `use as bounding box` as an option to the `\draw` that makes the `grid`, and add the loops after it, it looks better.