# Relative positioning of nodes to bounding box and to path operation

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-calc

I just tried to use the relative positioning of nodes with respect to the current bounding box of a `tikzpicture` as proposed in [Position node relative to current bounding box](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/274893/position-node-relative-to-current-bounding-box).

The proposed solution works fine (unsurprisingly of course) for the requested case. However, when trying to draw a path containing `to[out=...,in=...]` statements, the compiler fails with

> `Package tikz Error: (, +, coordinate, pic, or node expected`

As proposed in the Log, I

> Pretend that you're Hercule Poirot: Examine all clues,
>   and deduce the truth by order and method.

but up to now, nothing came out... If you have any ideas, thank you in advance.

Here is the MWE

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

% Relative positioning in tikzpicture as per https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/274893/position-node-relative-to-current-bounding-box
\newcommand\relcoord[2]{({$(current bounding box.south west)!#1!(current bounding box.south east)$} |- {$(current bounding box.south west)!#2!(current bounding box.north west)$})}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        % Bounding box setup
        \draw[black] (0,0) rectangle (10,10);
        \useasboundingbox \relcoord{0}{0} rectangle \relcoord{1}{1};
        % Red rectangle -> OK
        \draw[red] \relcoord{0.1}{0.1} rectangle \relcoord{0.8}{0.8};
        % Blude dashed lines -> OK
        \draw[blue,dashed] \relcoord{0.1}{0.1} -- \relcoord{0.1}{0.8} -- \relcoord{0.8}{0.8} -- \relcoord{0.8}{0.1} -- cycle;
        % Orange curves -> KO, to be commented for compilation
        \draw[orange,dashed] \relcoord{0.1}{0.1} to[out=90,in=-90] \relcoord{0.1}{0.8} to[out=0,in=180] \relcoord{0.8}{0.8} to[out=-90,in=90] \relcoord{0.8}{0.1} -- cycle;
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: While someone solves the question you can obey compiler and insert a `+` which implies to change relative values: `\draw[orange,dashed] \relcoord{0.1}{0.1} to[out=90,in=-90]  +\relcoord{0.0}{0.7} to[out=0,in=180]+\relcoord{0.7}{0} to[out=-90,in=90] +\relcoord{0.0}{-0.7} -- cycle;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think you need the `\relcoord` command at al if you fix the bounding box with `\useasboundingbox`.

You can define a style

```
\tikzset{
    use bounding box relative coordinates/.style={
        shift={(current bounding box.south west)},
        x={(current bounding box.south east)},
        y={(current bounding box.north west)}
    },
}
```

That ensures that `(0,0)` is at south west, `(1,0)` is at south east, `(0,1)` is at north west, and consequently, `(1,1)` is at north east of the current bounding box.

You can call this style in a `scope` with

```
\begin{scope}[use bounding box relative coordinates]
    <your commands>
\end{scope}
```

This way you don't even need the `calc` library to get this:

[image]

Full MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1mm]{standalone}

\tikzset{
    use bounding box relative coordinates/.style={
        shift={(current bounding box.south west)},
        x={(current bounding box.south east)},
        y={(current bounding box.north west)}
    },
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        % Bounding box setup
        \draw[black,use as bounding box] (-5,-5) rectangle (5,5);
        \begin{scope}[use bounding box relative coordinates]
            % Red rectangle -> OK
            \draw[red] (0.1,0.1) rectangle (0.8,0.8);
            % Blude dashed lines -> OK
            \draw[blue,dashed] (0.1,0.1) -- (0.1,0.8) -- (0.8,0.8) -- (0.8,0.1) -- cycle;
            % Orange curves -> OK
            \draw[orange,dashed] (0.1,0.1) to[out=90,in=-90] (0.1,0.8) to[out=0,in=180] (0.8,0.8) to[out=-90,in=90] (0.8,0.1) -- cycle;
        \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

Small remark on using `to` commands in this relative scope:

Imagine that you use `\draw[orange,dashed] (0.1,0.5) to[out=90,in=270] (0.8,0.5);` to draw a line with the perfect shape, depending on the rectangle you use as bounding box.

[image]

But now you would rather have a rectangle scaled only in `y` direction, so the wave form must scale with it. Only it does not.

[image]

At this point you might decide that is better to use the `.. controls (<handle1>) and (<handle2>) ..` drawing style, as follows: `\draw[green,line width=1pt,dashed] (0.1,0.5) .. controls ++(0,0.27) and ++(0,-0.27) .. (0.8,0.5);`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that's a different answer than excepted, but really nice though !

Comment: @BambOo is it useful for you in this form?

Comment: Yes, totally relevant for my application. It is really nice to be able to use the standard `(x,y)` syntax for relative postions

Comment: @BambOo great! Good to hear.

Comment: Just for the record, I noticed a small glitch. When trying to create a node on a path, the positioning seems to fail.

Comment: @BambOo Sorry for replying this late. What exactly fails? What do you try and what do you expect?

Comment: Sorry I didn't give much information. For instance, if I try to draw something like `\draw[] (0,0) -- node[pos=0.5](A){} (1,1)`, the `(A)` node is placed at `(0.5,0.5)`. However, replacing `--` with `to` which (I think) should be the same, node `(A)` is misplaced.

Comment: I can't seem to replicate this. Maybe you could ask a new question with MWE?

Comment: Actually, I just tested it on your code and it works fine, my bad. There must be an incompatibility with my original document

Comment: I will try to locate the incompatibility then maybe ask another question :) Thanks for the help

Comment: That would be the proper way to go I think. Good luck.