# Draw pointing arrows on beamer based on frame coordinate

Tags: beamer, arrows, coordinates, pointer

I would like to draw an arrow on top of a beamer frame based on the frame coordinates x and y. The idea is to use it as a pointer during a presentation, so that it should overlay text, figures and math alike.

If that is possible the idea is to build a command like:

```
\newcommand<>{\Arrow}[2]{
  \only#3{
    \DrawArrow{#1}{#2}
  }
}
```

So that it could be used in a frame just by: `\Arrow{x}{y}`

[image]

I looked around but couldn't find anything that I could adapt in order to do that.

Thank you!

---

Here is the final code I used based on BambOo code:

```
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows}

\tikzset{
  use page relative coordinates/.style={
    shift={(current page.south west)},
    x={(current page.south east)},
    y={(current page.north west)}
  },
}

\newcommand<>{\Pointer}[2]{
  \onslide#3{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,use page relative coordinates]
      \node (x) at (#1,#2) {};
      \draw[stealth-] (x) %
      node[overlay,single arrow,draw=none,fill=red!70,anchor=tip,rotate=60,opacity=0.75]%
      {\hspace{0.5cm}~};
    \end{tikzpicture}
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX - LaTeX! [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please don't post code fragments. Instead, put your fragments into a complete compilable  document that shows the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a variation of the nice [`use bounding box relative coordinates`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/445311/141947) based on the `current page` anchors.

See `tikz` manual section 17.13.2

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{
    use page relative coordinates/.style={
        shift={(current page.south west)},
        x={(current page.south east)},
        y={(current page.north west)}
    },
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{title}{subtitle}

    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-a}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,use page relative coordinates]
        \node (x) at (0.6,0.5) {x};
        \draw[stealth-] (x) --++ (-45:0.2) node[fill=white,draw,at end] {OOOOOh here is an X !};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! It worked perfectly!