# How to have a rectangular spotlight using TikZ in beamer?

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

I am trying to change the shape of the highlighted area in the `MWE` below (based on [this @BambOo's solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/529920/beamer-using-a-spotlight-to-highlight-a-part-of-an-image)).

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{
    use page relative coordinates/.style={
        shift={(current page.south west)},
        x={(current page.south east)},
        y={(current page.north west)}
    },
}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{frame}{title}{subtitle}
    \begin{block}{Block title}
        Some content
    \end{block}
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-a}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,use page relative coordinates]
    \fill[opacity=0.5,black] (0,0) rectangle (1,1) (0.25,0.5) circle (2cm);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Neither

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,use page relative coordinates]
    \fill[opacity=0.5,black] (0,0) rectangle (1,1) (0.15,0.15) rectangle (0.2,0.2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

nor

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,use page relative coordinates]
    \fill[opacity=0.5,black] (0,0) rectangle (1,1); 
    \fill[opacity=0,black] (0.15,0.15) rectangle (0.2,0.2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

does the job.

How can I get it working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add `even odd rule` option, it works. Why? I don't know, it seems that combining a rectangle with a circle doesn't need to explicitely fix the rule

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{
    use page relative coordinates/.style={
        shift={(current page.south west)},
        x={(current page.south east)},
        y={(current page.north west)}
    },
}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{frame}{title}{subtitle}
    \begin{block}{Block title}
        Some content
    \end{block}
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-a}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,use page relative coordinates]
    \filldraw[opacity=0.5, black, even odd rule] (0,0) rectangle (1,1) (0.2,0.2) rectangle (0.38,0.6);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]