# Labeling a diagram exported from Paraview using TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am using Paraview to visualize some data. Is it possible to label the diagram taken from Paraview using the TikZ package. My knowledge about this package is limited. My labelled image would look something like:

[image]

Is it possible to create such a label using TikZ? If yes how can this be achieved?

Comment: Would the answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9559/drawing-on-an-image-with-tikz) solve your problem? If yes, the [second answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/9562/184389) gives you a way to help you find the right coordinates (don't forget to remove the grid when you are done).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though multiple solutions have been proposed as noted by KersouMan. I am personally very fond of [the solution proposed by Max](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/445311/141947) to a closely related problem of mine. So if you like this answer please upvote his.

I added the other `node`s with some comments to help you unederstand the script. Of course all of this supposes that you actually have your `Paraview` plot available as a graphics file (e.g. pdf, png, jpg ...)

**EDIT** Addition of a node connected to two arrows.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\tikzset{
    % Tikz style used to work in relative coordinates to the underlying picture
    % From https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/445311/141947
    use bounding box relative coordinates/.style={
        shift={(current bounding box.south west)},
        x={(current bounding box.south east)},
        y={(current bounding box.north west)}
    },
    % Shortcut to avoid repeating stuff afterwards
    label/.style={fill=white,draw=black},
}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
% Import picture and select it as bounding box
\node[use as bounding box] {\includegraphics{example-image-a}};
% Activate relative positioning of points
\begin{scope}[use bounding box relative coordinates]
    \node[label] at (0.8,0.8) {TE};
    \node[label] at (0.8,0.2) {LE};
    % Create an arrow between point at coordinates (0.2,0.4) and a point a 60° angle and 0.5 distance from the first one
    \draw[stealth-] (0.2,0.4) --++ (60:0.5) node[pos=1,label,anchor=west]{Horseshoe vortex} ;
    % Create a label, then draw arrrows linked to it
    \node[label] (IndVortLabel) at (0.3,0.3) {Induced vortices};
    \draw[] (IndVortLabel.west) edge[-stealth] (0.1,0.35)
            (IndVortLabel.west) edge[-stealth] (0.1,0.25);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Dear BambOo, can you please tell the necessary changes to be made to in the `\draw[stealth-]`  to achieve [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YkRwl.jpg). I am not able to figure out.

Comment: @Giri, I edited my answer. However, you should have a look at the [`tikz` manual](http://distrib-coffee.ipsl.jussieu.fr/pub/mirrors/ctan/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) there are a lot of examples to show you how the package works