# Changing the color of the arrow in TikZ using xcolor package

Tags: tikz-pgf

The following is the MWE (Following code is taken from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/540965/labeling-a-diagram-exported-from-paraview-using-tikz/540971?noredirect=1#comment1366608_540971), with slight modifications):

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\tikzset{
    use bounding box relative coordinates/.style={
        shift={(current bounding box.south west)},
        x={(current bounding box.south east)},
        y={(current bounding box.north west)}
    },
    label/.style={draw=golden-rod},
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[use as bounding box] {\includegraphics{example-image-a}};
\begin{scope}[use bounding box relative coordinates]
    \node[label][golden-rod] (Label) at (0.3,0.3) {GR};
    \draw[golden-rod] (Label.west) edge[-stealth] (0.1,0.35)
                      (Label.west) edge[-stealth] (0.1,0.25);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The problem I am facing is that I am not able to use the color *Goldenrod* available from the `xcolor` package. When I run the above code, I get the following errors:

1. Package pgf Error: Unknown arrow tip kind 'golden'
2. Package pgf Error: Unknown arrow tip kind 'rod'
3. Package xcolor Error: Undefined color 'golden-rod'

When I change "golden-rod" to "Goldenrod" I get the following errors:

1. Package pgf Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/Goldenrod' and I am
   going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.
2. Package xcolor Error: Undefined color 'Goldenrod'.

In general, I am not able to use the colors whose name has two parts. Is there a way around this?

Comment: `xcolor` defines a color called `Goldenrod` as opposed to `golden-rod`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apart from the typo (`golden-rod` instead of the correct `Goldenrod`), there are two more issues that must be addressed to make the code compilable.

First, it should be `color=Goldenrod` if you want the box border and the text in the color Goldenrod or `draw=Goldenrow` if you want black text inside of a Goldenrod-colored box.

(This solves `Package pgf Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/Goldenrod' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.`)

Second, the `goldenrod` color is only defined when loading `xcolor` with the `svgnames` option. Since you `tikz`  internally also loads `xcolor` you can not use `\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}`. Instead, I'd suggest using `\PassOptionsToPackage{svgnames}{xcolor}
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}`.

(This solves: `Package xcolor Error: Undefined color 'Goldenrod'.`)

A full, compilable MWE would look like the following:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{svgnames}{xcolor}
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\tikzset{
    use bounding box relative coordinates/.style={
        shift={(current bounding box.south west)},
        x={(current bounding box.south east)},
        y={(current bounding box.north west)}
    },
    label/.style={draw=Goldenrod},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[use as bounding box] {\includegraphics{example-image-a}};
\begin{scope}[use bounding box relative coordinates]
    \node[label][color=Goldenrod] (Label) at (0.3,0.3) {GR};
    \draw[Goldenrod] (Label.west) edge[-stealth] (0.1,0.35)
                      (Label.west) edge[-stealth] (0.1,0.25);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I am required to use the above solution with the `scrreprt – Koma-Script 'report' class.` Can you please tell, how to load `xcolor` with the `\documentclass{scrreprt}` ? I used `\PassOptionsToPackage{svgnames}{xcolor}` in the preamble before `\tikzset{.......}`. I am getting the same error  `Package pgf Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/Goldenrod' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.`

Comment: `\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}`.