# How to export a diagram labelled using TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats

The following is the MWE (Following code is taken from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/540965/labeling-a-diagram-exported-from-paraview-using-tikz/540971?noredirect=1#comment1366608_540971), with slight modifications):

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\tikzset{
    use bounding box relative coordinates/.style={
        shift={(current bounding box.south west)},
        x={(current bounding box.south east)},
        y={(current bounding box.north west)}
    },
    label/.style={draw=black},
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[use as bounding box] {\includegraphics{example-image-a}};
\begin{scope}[use bounding box relative coordinates]
    \node[label] (Label) at (0.3,0.3) {GR};
    \draw[stealth-] (Label.west) edge[-stealth] (0.1,0.35)
                      (Label.west) edge[-stealth] (0.1,0.25);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I am using this piece of code to just label a diagram. The format of the diagram imported to LaTeX is `.jpeg` . I intend to use the labelled diagram in  a PowerPoint presentation. Is it possible to export the diagram labelled using TikZ?

Comment: Could you please explain a bit more what you mean by "Is it possible to export the diagram labelled using TikZ?"? You can create a pdf, say, which you import in PowerPoint.

Comment: I am using LaTeX for writing a report. This report contains images (Labelled using TikZ) along with explanation. I would like to export only the labelled images preferably in .jpeg format.

Comment: I see. I believe `externalize` can do that. See e.g. [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/350081/194703).

Comment: Many people use [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) to create PNG or JPEG from PDF files created with LaTeX.  But, with PPT on my Mac I've have best results simply dragging the PDF file from preview into a new slide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer finds its motivation from this [source](https://www.overleaf.com/blog/613-tip-of-the-week-how-to-convert-typeset-pdf-pages-into-raster-image-formats).

For those of you who are using Overleaf, I found that this is fairly straightforward. First you need to compile the code once, so that the `pdf` file is available. Then create a file with the name `latexmkrc` and paste `END { system('convert -density 600 -background white -flatten output.pdf page2.png'); }`. Then recompile the project one more time. Now go to *Logs and output files* and scroll down to the end of the page, you should be able to find a file with the name `page2.png`. Click on that. Your image file will open in a new tab.